# What if I pay with card with no money on it?

Tags: legal, bookings, payment-cards, cancellations

I want to cancel the reservation on my hotel. And they say that they'll charge me with €900, but I don't have any money on my card. Can they do it?

Comment: It depends on the card and account  if they can do it; and the account my reflect a debt. if you know it is not legal, dispute/reverse the charge with the bank. That is why I normally give hotels/bookpool/aliexpress virtual cards with limited funds to avoid abuses. Why such an high value?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it sounds like it might be a last minute cancellation, where many hotels charge a high percentage or the full cost if the cancellation is within a certain number of days to the stay.  In this case, the visitor agreed to the cancellation terms, so a dispute or reversal of charges could very well be seen as fraudulent by the card company when the hotel responds to the dispute.

Comment: My suspicion too...however was waiting for the OP to confirm that. In that case, I would make arrangements to have the money in the account before they make the charge, go to the holidays, or failing that, give the holidays to some member of the family. Or provide proof I really cant go, for instance a medical certificate.

Comment: Besides to consider about the bank card, if the hotel does the whole thing according to the booking regulation and you booked with your real name and address, then you owe the amount to the hotel. The hotel can get the money via juristic way, and situation will be even worse if the hotel is in your home country. And important, in some countries, authorize the payee with a invalid card or insufficient amount is an issue in terms of criminal law.

Answer (score 1):

The consequences (for you) depend what kind of card it is (is it a pre-paid card, a debit/check card or a credit card); however as a simple matter if the card has no balance - and no "overcharge" feature, the request will be rejected with a notice stating the same.

Keep in mind that they may have pre-authorized the charge (also called a "hold") if so, the money is effectively blocked for them and in this case they can still receive the funds.

If you are in doubt, you can check with your bank or card issuer.

Comment: Depending on the type of the account or the card and the plafond, the request may not be rejected but turned into a lending with a somewhat abusive interest. e.g. an over drafted  account